# AdvAgg Update & Settings Problem

Tags: performance, css-js-aggregation

I see this warning I go to update the database.

> Notice: Constant ADVAGG_MOD_CSS_DEFER already defined in
>   include_once() (line 172 of
>   /home/valerie/public_html/permanentmakeupcornwall.com/sites/all/modules/advagg/advagg_mod/advagg_mod.module)

The other problem is the advagg drop downs do not work; when I click on Experimental Settings for CSS it does not drop down for me to tick the box. I need to tick to optimise css delivery and clear the error on google page speed test for render blocking above the fold.

Comment: What version of advagg module are you using?

Comment: Also have you restarted your web server process and pho to clear any opcache you have.

Comment: I am using Advagg 7 x 2.15

Comment: I do not know what pho is or opcache but I have restarted my vps server with graceful reboot but no improvement in advagg drop downs

Comment: i have run chron and cleared all caches many times too.  Is there anything else I can try to get advagg to work again?  I believe the error message i have as shown in my question above needs to be resolved before advagg will work again.  any chance you can help me please?

Comment: This is my first website that i built for my sister using drupal and I have a lot of problems to resolve and this is my first experience with drupal answers, so I will be posting a lot more questions here if there is a mentor available that would be great!